# How can I update value every 20 and 30 minutes?

Tags: mysql, events

I have a table ‘comenzi’, each order has a value for in progress, and another for ready  and data. Each order when it is created has the values for in progress and ready equal to 0. I want to update the values for in progress and ready with 1 min ,after 20 min, then 30 min after the order has been done, the value from data that has the form 2020-05-25 09:41:00.

I need a way to update these values, a function or an event in database.

Comment: Does setTimeout or setInterval work for you? May you share your efforts so far?

Comment: I think you need cron jobs for things like this

Comment: Or an Event Scheduler in the database

Comment: Event procedure started by [Event Scheduler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/event-scheduler.html) (for example, each minute) may do this.

Comment: Yes, i tried with event scheduler in database, but i cannot find a way to update like i said. I set recurring event every 5 minutes with this: UPDATE comenzi set `pregatit`=1 WHERE `pregatit`=0 AND TIME_TO_SEC(data) > TIME_TO_SEC(CURRENT_TIME()) - 1200

Comment: Event procedure is common stored procedure (with additional properties specific for scheduled object), and update is performed in it by the common way

Comment: `WHERE ... TIME_TO_SEC(data) > TIME_TO_SEC(CURRENT_TIME()) - 1200` is bad practice, use `WHERE ... datetime_column > NOW() - INTERVAL 20 MINUTE`

Comment: Yes, it works, but not like I want. Now I set the event recurring every 1 minute and if order is in interval of 20 minutes or 30 minutes, it updates the value, but i want to check the value every minute and update only if it passed 20 minutes and 30 minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was dealing with something using events just yesterday on a pet project. You could use a similar approach.

This code uses a `creation` column, which is just a `TIMESTAMP` column with a default value of `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` (because I don't have your data) and a `value` column (default value 0), which goes from 1 - 2 (you can modify this code to suit your needs).

The `SET` value uses `CASE`s to check how long ago the order was created. Then it updates the value accordingly. You can change up the event to update whichever columns / time cases you'll need.

```
CREATE DEFINER =`root`@`localhost` EVENT `progressEvent`
  ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE STARTS '2020-09-01 00:00:00'
  ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE DO UPDATE comenzi
SET `value` = (
  CASE WHEN (creation < (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE))
  THEN 2
  CASE WHEN (creation < (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 20 MINUTE))
  THEN 1
  END)
WHERE value < 2
```

Edit: Changed it up so that it checks every minute and only 20/ 30 minutes.